# Connecting MySQL to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I tried to connect Android to MySQL through php. There's no error in my code but I guess, there is something wrong. I tried to run the app but the title of the Dialog box only displays. I think the `result` might be the problem?

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] voids) {
        String type = "login";

        String login_url = "http://192.168.254.109/ITSP/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String username = voids[1];
                String password =voids[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

And by getting the value from here:

```
public void OnLogin(View view){
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}
```

I have just used simple code for PHP connection. `(conn.php)`

When I press the `Log In` button, only the `alertDialog = "Login Status"` are displayed.

Comment: Try to used retrofit 2.0 it is easy to understand and implement.

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ . I use this code for php and android and i works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Ion` library rather than using `AsyncTask`. It will reduce the lines of code and at the same time is more accurate than the `AsyncTask`

https://github.com/koush/ion

This is the github link for the library.

what you are trying to do in your code can be implemented like this

```
    Ion.with(getContext())
    .load("POST","http://192.168.254.109/ITSP/login.php")
    .setBodyParameter("username", username)
    .setBodyParameter("password", password)
    .asJsonObject()  //change it to .asString() if u expect the response from the server in a string format
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        // do stuff with the result or error
       //if you change the return to .asString() u need to change the callback method to <String> instead of<JsonObject>
});
```

Comment: Let me know if any error pops. I will be glad to help

Comment: How can i implement this code to my code? I'm just a newbie. I hope you can rewrite my code, for me to understand it more. Thanks by the way :D

Comment: ERROR:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1.